# How to disable horizontal infinite scrolling in Bing Map Control

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, pixelsense

Someone please advise if there are any ways that i can disable infinite horizontal scrolling of map. 
Please see Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/78TuM.jpg

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="BingMap.SurfaceWindow1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"

Title="BingMap"  
>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="1080" Width="1920" >
    <m:Map Mode="Road" Name="globalmap" CredentialsProvider="BingMapsKey"
               Center="25.257505,51.571884"
         ZoomLevel="2.5" >
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain more of what your problem is? And maybe supply the code that you are using that is causing this?

Comment: Switched to ArcGIS Api for WPF and now able to disable infinite horizontal scrolling of Map by setting wraparound method.